# How can I build a bilingual website in PHP?

Tags: php

Currently, I am building a PHP website running on localhost, as you often see on most websites, there is a multi-language conversion function suitable for geographical areas. How can I do that with PHP? The languages I'm trying to build for my PHP website are English and Vietnamese. My idea is to have a language switch button. Can you give me a solution or a keyword to be able to do this.

I have consulted on the Internet, they have suggested that it is possible to declare language files, for example lang_en.php and lang_vi.php, and then use session to check to display the appropriate language.
I don't use php frameworks but only write websites in pure PHP.